# Why do cats sleep in a curled up position?

Tags: sleep, pets, cat

I've noticed that cats will usually sleep curled up like ball, heads down and titled, with tails near their face. Is there any specific reason that cats would have a tendency to sleep this way?

Comment: Cats are not the only animal that does this.  Dogs do, as do most small mammals I've seen.  FTM, except for lacking a tail, so do I.  There are a lot of possible reasons: it conserves heat, protects one's belly from attack, is just more comfortable...

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 